# React-bootstrap delete confirmation modal disappears immediately it launches on button click

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am a beginner in react and I am practicing crud operations on recursive data from an api backend. The idea is to delete an item when a user confirms they want to delete. I intend to utilize useParams to get the id from the url then go ahead and perform the deletion in the database. Unfortunately the modal launches and disappears hence I cannot go ahead and perform the deletion.

An answer on a similar question suggests using preventDefault() which I tried as shown below. It achieves the desired result and the modal stays in place but it strips off the route from the url and only shows http://localhost:3000 hence I cannot get the id which is key in deletion. The answer will not work in my case.

```
const handleDeleteShow = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setModalDeleteShow(true);
};

<a href={`/menu/delete/${id}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className="text-danger ml-4"  onClick={(e) => handleDeleteShow(e)}/></a>
```

Another answer said the behaviour happens as a result of duplicate bootstrap reference which I can't seem to find not unless I am blind to it. I have installed react-bootstrap and as their documentation suggested I have included the bootstrap css as a CDN in the index.html. Let me also mention that I have provided the CDN for jquery and bootstrap.js in the same file.

I want the modal to stay till either the delete or cancel button is clicked and for the full delete route to show when the modal lauches. Kindly help me figure what is wrong. I am also open to any other approaches to achieving this.

Find below my code.

**Menu.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Recursive from './Recursive';
import axios from 'axios';


const Menu = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/menu/')
        .then(response => {
            setMenu(response.data)
        });
    }, []);

    
    return (
        <div>
            {menu.map(item => {
                return(
                <Recursive key={item.id} {...item}/>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Menu;
```

**Recursive.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import DeleteConfirmation from './DeleteConfirmation';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEdit, faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Recursive = ({id, name, children}) => {

    const [modalDeleteShow, setModalDeleteShow] = useState(false);
    const handleDeleteClose = () => setModalDeleteShow(false);
    const handleDeleteShow = () => setModalDeleteShow(true);

    return (
        <>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8">
                <ol className="tree-structure">
                    <li key={id}>
                        <span className="num">{id}</span>
                        {name}
                        <div className="float-right">
                            <a href={`/menu/edit/${id}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} className="text-primary mr-1"/></a> 
                            <a href={`/menu/delete/${id}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className="text-danger ml-4"  onClick={() => handleDeleteShow()}/></a>
                        </div>
                        <ol>
                            {children ?
                                children.map((child, index) => {
                                    return(
                                        <>
                                            <li key={child.id} id={child.id} >
                                                <span className="num">{child.id}</span>
                                                {child.name}
                                            </li>
                                            <a href={`/menu/edit/${child.id}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} className="text-primary mr-1"/></a> 
                                            <a href={`/menu/delete/${child.id}`}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} className="text-danger ml-1"  onClick={() => handleDeleteShow()}/></a>
                                        </>
                                    );
                                })
                            :null
                            } 
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <DeleteConfirmation showModal={modalDeleteShow} hideModal={handleDeleteClose}/>
        </>
        
    );
};

export default Recursive;
```

**DeleteConfirmation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

const DeleteConfirmation = ({ showModal, hideModa}) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const { id } = useParams()

    const handleDelete = () => {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/menu/delete/${id}/`)
        .then(() => {
            history.push({
                pathname: '/',
            });
            window.location.reload();
        });
    };

    return (
        <Modal show={showModal} onHide={hideModal}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Delete Confirmation</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
            <div className="alert alert-danger">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this?
                </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={hideModal}>
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleDelete}>
                    Delete
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
};

export default DeleteConfirmation;
```

Comment: may be not related but there is a typo here `({ showModal, hideModa})`

Comment: with `<a>` tag you are redirecting to menu. React component is unmounted, and your state is gone now. You can test it by putting a console log in `useEffect`